# Dynamic loading and weak symbol resolution

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading, symbol-table, weak-linking

Analyzing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20568235/1468366) I found out some things about behavior of weak symbol resolution in the context of dynamic loading (`dlopen`) on Linux. Now I'm looking for the specifications governing this.

Let's take [an example](https://gist.github.com/gagern/7989748). Suppose there is a program `a` which dynamically loads libraries `b.so` and `c.so`, in that order. If `c.so` depends on two other libraries `foo.so` (actually `libgcc.so` in that example) and `bar.so` (actually `libpthread.so`), then usually symbols exported by `bar.so` can be used to satisfy weak symbol linkages in `foo.so`. But if `b.so` also depends on `foo.so` but not on `bar.so`, then these weak symbols will apparently not be linked against `bar.so`. It seems as if `foo.so` inkages only look for symbols from `a` and `b.so` and all their dependencies.

This makes sense, to some degree, since otherwise loading `c.so` might change the behavior of `foo.so` at some point where `b.so` has already been using the library. On the other hand, in the question that got me started this caused quite a bit of trouble, so I wonder whether there is a way around this problem. And in order to find ways around, I first need a good understanding about the very exact details how symbol resolution in these cases is specified.

**What is the specification or other technical document to define correct behavior in these scenarios?**

Comment: Did you have a look at [this PDF](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf)? Lots of interesting data, but not sure if it includes what you look for.

Comment: @rodrigo: Not sure if it was this or something similar, but so far all the ELF docs I found only describe dynamic linking prior to execution of a binary, not the linking involved in dynamically loaded objects. It is a long document, and I might have looked in the wrong places, but so far it seems not to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: And what about this [Drepper post](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-hacker/2000-06/msg00029.html) and its more or less [related doc](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (see section 1.5.2)? As I interpret it, weak symbols are only use for static linking. So `dlopen()` would not make a difference between weak and strong symbols.

Comment: These rantings seem relevant http://notmysock.org/blog/php/weak-symbols-arent.html

Comment: @rodrigo: Sorry it took me so long to try this out. It seems you are right, contrary to my belief, an unresokved symbol in loading a shared object will not cause that loading to fail. I thought weak was needed for that, but that's not the case. Anyway, section 1.5.4 of the doc you linked is the most useful I've read so far, since it is very detailed on the order in which libraries are processed, and the various settings that control it. If you (or perhaps someone else) could sum that up, I'd gladly award my bounty for it. I'd do it myself, but in that case the bounty would be lost, so I don't.

Comment: @MvG: I appreciate the offer, but I'm not confident about writing a proper answer to this question, or I would have written it a while ago. I just happened to know about those documents and some high level stuff, but I'm lost in the details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, the authoritative documentation is the source code. Most distributions of Linux use glibc or its fork, eglibc. In the source code for both, the file that should document dlopen() reads as follows:

manual/libdl.texi

```
@c FIXME these are undocumented:
@c dladdr
@c dladdr1
@c dlclose
@c dlerror
@c dlinfo
@c dlmopen
@c dlopen
@c dlsym
@c dlvsym
```

What technical specification there is can be drawn from the [ELF specification](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) and the POSIX standard. The ELF specification is what makes a weak symbol meaningful. POSIX is the actual [specification for dlopen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) itself.

This is what I find to be the most relevant portion of the ELF specification.

> When the link editor searches archive libraries, it extracts archive
>   members that contain definitions of undefined global symbols. The
>   member’s definition may be either a global or a weak symbol.

The ELF specification makes no reference to dynamic loading so the rest of this paragraph is my own interpretation. The reason I find the above relevant is that resolving symbols occurs at a single "when". In the example you give, when program `a` dynamically loads `b.so`, the dynamic loader attempts to resolve undefined symbols. It may end up doing so with either global or weak symbols. When the program then dynamically loads `c.so`, the dynamic loader again attempts to resolve undefined symbols. In the scenario you describe, symbols in `b.so` were resolved with weak symbols. Once resolved, those symbols are no longer undefined. It doesn't matter if global or weak symbols were used to defined them. They're already no longer undefined by the time `c.so` is loaded.

The ELF specification gives no precise definition of what a link editor is or when the link editor must combine object files. Presumably it's a non-issue because the document has dynamic-linking in mind.

POSIX describes some of the dlopen() functionality but leaves much up to the implementation, including the substance of your question. POSIX makes no reference to the ELF format or weak symbols in general. For systems implementing dlopen() there need not even be any notion of weak symbols.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html

POSIX compliance is part of another standard, the Linux Standard Base. Linux distributions may or may not choose to follow these standards and may or may not go to the trouble of being certified. For example, I understand that a formal Unix certification by Open Group is quite expensive -- hence the abundance of "Unix-like" systems.

An interesting point about the standards compliance of dlopen() is made on the [Wikipedia article for dynamic loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading). dlopen(), as mandated by POSIX, returns a void*, but C, as mandated by ISO, says that a void* is a pointer to an object and such a pointer is not necessarily compatible with a function pointer.

> The fact remains that any conversion between function and object
>   pointers has to be regarded as an (inherently non-portable)
>   implementation extension, and that no "correct" way for a direct
>   conversion exists, since in this regard the POSIX and ISO standards
>   contradict each other.

The standards that do exist contradict and what standards documents there are may not be especially meaningful anyway. Here's Ulrich Drepper writing about his disdain for Open Group and their "specifications".

http://udrepper.livejournal.com/8511.html

Similar sentiment is expressed in the post linked by rodrigo.

> The reason I've made this change is not really to be more conformant
>   (it's nice but no reason since nobody complained about the old
>   behaviour).

After looking into it, I believe the proper answer to the question as you've asked it is that there is no right or wrong behavior for `dlopen()` in this regard. Arguably, once a search has resolved a symbol it is no longer undefined and in subsequent searches the dynamic loader will not attempt to resolve the already defined symbol.

Finally, as you state in the comments, what you describe in the original post is not correct. Dynamically loaded shared libraries can be used to resolve undefined symbols in previously dynamically loaded shared libraries. In fact, this isn't limited to undefined symbols in dynamically loaded code. Here is an example in which the executable itself has an undefined symbol that is resolved through dynamic loading.

main.c

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void say_hi(void);

int main(void) {
    void* symbols_b = dlopen("./dyload.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    /* uh-oh, forgot to define this function */
    /* better remember to define it in dyload.so */
    say_hi();
    return 0;
}
```

dyload.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void say_hi(void) {
    puts("dyload.so: hi");
}
```

Compile and run.

```
gcc-4.8 main -fpic -ldl -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -o main
gcc-4.8 dyload.c -shared -fpic -o dyload.so
$ ./main
dyload.so: hi
```

Note that the main executable itself was compiled as PIC.

Comment: This is what I call an excelent answer!

Comment: Glibc linker ignores weakness of symbols unless `LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK` is specified (see the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)).